# Not display decimal point in sprintf for integers

Tags: r, character

I need to convert some numeric values to characters.  I want to show trailing zeros if relevant, and no decimal place if the number is an integer.  For example, in the code below, I need my output to be `"11"  "0.30"    "0.00050" "3.1" "4.6"`.  How do I get the 11 to display as "11" not "11."?

```r
sprintf('%#.2g', c(11, 0.301, 0.000502, 3.12, 4.56))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the trailing . like this:

```
sprintf('%#.2g', c(11, 0.301, 0.000502, 3.12, 4.56)) |> stringr::str_remove("[.]$")
#> [1] "11"      "0.30"    "0.00050" "3.1"     "4.6"
```

Comment: I replaced the |> with %>% and it worked in R

Comment: Yes, they are mostly equivalent. If you have an R verision >=4.1, you can use the native pipe `|>`